# Using a HashMap with my object as a key

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable

I want to make a simple note reminder app that uses hashMap when the date is the key and the value is the text.
I have a Panel class(GUI), the hash-table class (Reminder.java), and a "MyDateClass.java" that represent a date for my purposes.

My gui is made of 3 JComboBox (day,month,year), One text area and 2 buttons - "Save", "Load".

The 2 buttons in the GUI Panel:

```
    butSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener () {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            MyDateClass chosenDate = new MyDateClass(cbYear.getSelectedIndex()+2013,cbMonth.getSelectedIndex()+1, cb.getSelectedIndex()+1);
            if(!remind.isReminderExists(chosenDate)){
                remind.save(chosenDate, tfReminder.getText());
                System.out.println("reminder doesnt exists");
            }}
    });
    butLoad.addActionListener(new ActionListener () {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("tryin to load");
            MyDateClass chosenDate = new MyDateClass(cbYear.getSelectedIndex()+2013,cbMonth.getSelectedIndex()+1, cb.getSelectedIndex()+1);

            if(remind.isReminderExists(chosenDate)){
                remind.Load(chosenDate);
                System.out.println("reminder exists");
            }}      
    });
```

Reminder class:

```
public class Reminder {

    Map<MyDateClass,String> reminderMap;

    public Reminder(){
        reminderMap = new HashMap<MyDateClass,String>();
    }
    public boolean isReminderExists(MyDateClass date){
        return reminderMap.containsKey(date);
    }
    public void save(MyDateClass date, String Input){
        System.out.println("Trying to save");
        reminderMap.put(date, Input);
    }
    public void Load(MyDateClass date){
        System.out.println("Trying to load");
        String output;
        output = reminderMap.get(date);
        System.out.println(output);
    }
```

So after i push the save button i get from the console:

```
Trying to save
reminder doesnt exists
```

But then i push the Load button for the same date and

```
if(remind.isReminderExists(chosenDate))
```

Isnt triggerd.

**What might be the problem?**

Do i need to override hashCode() and equals() ? I genereted them but i dont if and how to change the equals() (do i need to manipulate it to compare both dates? How do i do that if "this" refers to the reminder Object)

Comment: You need to override `hashCode` and `equals`.  `equals` needs to return true if your objects are conceptually equal, and `hashCode` needs to return a consistent value for a given set your object contents, such that all `equals` objects will have the same `hashCode`.

Comment: You should override hasCode and equals in your `MyDateClass` code.

Comment: I override it in the MyDateClass class ? any hint on how to override them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
@Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(o == this) return true;
    if(!(o instanceof MyDateClass)) return false;
    MyDateClass that = (MyDateClass) o;

    // use == for primitives
    // use .compare for primitive wrappers where available
    // use .equals for objects 
    return this.ivar1 == that.ivar2 &&
           this.ivar2 == that.ivar2; //etc...    
}

// equal objects must have equal hash codes
@Override public int hashCode() {
    int result = 17;
    result = 31 * result + ivar1;
    result = 31 * result + ivar2;
    return result;
}
```

Write JUnits to test for reflexive, symmetric, transitive, and consistent results.

Answer (score 1):

As I know your problem clearly, I think that this function always return false. Because  `date`(parameter) and the object in `reminderMap` have difference reference. So they can not be equal.

```
public boolean isReminderExists(MyDateClass date){
    return reminderMap.containsKey(date);
}
```

If you want to use `containsKey` function of `HashMap`, maybe you should use `String` or Number instead of `MyDateClass`. I mean you should convert object of `MyDateClass` to `String` value before inserting it into `reminderMap`.

```
public boolean isReminderExists(String date){
    return reminderMap.containsKey(date);
}
```

Otherwise, you can implement your code as [Hot Licks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/581994/hot-licks) mention.